# Nginx Ingress Path Based Routing 304 Not Modified or not routing

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-ingress, rancher

We are using RKE cluster on rancher,
My NGİNX controller version=1.2.0-rancher1

I want to appy path based ingress routing on my cluster,
For example, if my host:http://test.koc.gov.tr
I have 25 frontend microservices containers on cluster and I want to reach them by path based ingress routing.
For example, I want to reach my tob service with ingress http://test.koc.gov.tr/tob,
I want to reach my sso service with ingress http://test.koc.gov.tr/sso,

My NGİNX cant route like what I want,

I am taking 304 Not Modified below yaml configration

I am sharing below my ingress yaml, Anyone can help me about this situation.

[My yaml File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h72bV.png)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: user-56464
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port
      80;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-15T05:06:05Z"
  generation: 21
  labels:
    cattle.io/creator: norman
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: nginx-ingress-controller
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-05-15T05:06:28Z"
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
          f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: {}
          f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: {}
    manager: Mozilla
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-05-22T15:25:21Z"
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/creatorId: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/ingressState: {}
          f:field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: {}
          f:nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:cattle.io/creator: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
    manager: rancher
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-05-22T15:36:39Z"
  name: bilge-tob
  namespace: tob
  resourceVersion: "1635877"
  uid: dc47d412-ce5d-40fb-94f5-d4e6999361b9
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.koc.gov.tr
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: tob-frontend
          servicePort: 8443
        path: /tob
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
```

I have 25 frontend microservices containers on cluster and I want to reach them by path based ingress routing.
For example, I want to reach my tob service with ingress http://test.koc.gov.tr/tob,
I want to reach my sso service with ingress http://test.koc.gov.tr/sso,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499298 ı checked following answer and my 304 problem is solved but This time I cant reah my application although all request is 200(ok)